# dynamically storing prime numbers in a 1d array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

I am making a program which stores prime numbers in a given range into an 1-d array dynamically. I have read about dynamic memory allocation in c,but i don't know what's wrong with my code. 
Initially I define an "isprime" function which checks whether a number is prime or not and if the number is prime it returns 1.
After that I use a for loop which helps in storing of prime numbers in an array.
In the for loop I use an if statement which checks whether the number in the range input by the user is prime or not,and if it is prime it is stored in an array p for which memory is allocated dynamically using malloc.
But in the array p no prime numbers are stored and instead garbage values are stored,I don't know why prime numbers are not getting stored in my array?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int isprime(int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<sqrt(n);i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
main()
{
    int *p,i,n,j=1;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(isprime(i)&&i!=0&&i!=1)
        {
            p=malloc(j*sizeof(int));//Memory allocation for p should increase as more prime no.s are stored
            p[j-1]=i;
            j++;

        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",p[1]);//garbage value is printed instead of any prime no.
}
```

Comment: you need `realloc` not `malloc`

Comment: `isprime(4)` return `1`.

Comment: You'll need to change `for(i=2;i<sqrt(n);i++)` to `for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)` so that you spot that 9 and 25 are not primes.  You probably don't want to call `sqrt()` on each iteration, though your optimizer may fix your oversight for you.  (The spaces in the rewrite make it easier to read; they're not critical to the functioning of the code.  Spaces are cheap; use them appropriately.)

Comment: Aside: If in `isprime()` you first check if `n` is 2 (prime) or is even number (not prime) you can halve the execution time with `for(i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2)`.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` for the functions (malloc, calloc, realloc, free)

Comment: the `main()` function only has two valid signatures (and modern C does not assume that the return type is `int`) so this line: `main()` should be either: `int main( void )` or `int main( int argc, char *argv[] );`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the usage of `malloc()` does not carry forward anything from where the pointer previously pointed.  Strongly suggest using `realloc()` which does carry forward the prior contents.  HOWEVER, before assigning the target variable, check (!=NULL) the returned value.  Otherwise, the original pointer will be overlayed with NULL, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: the posted code has some serious memory leak.  The line: `p=malloc(j*sizeof(int));` is loosing the prior memory pointer.  Suggest using: `void *temp = realloc( p, j*sizeof(int) );  if !temp ) { // handle error, cleanup, and exit }  // implied else, realloc successful  p = temp;`

Comment: to avoid some implicit conversions, the variable 'j' should be declared via: `size_t j=0;'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler doesn't care, but us humans do) 1) follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement. 2) follow commas with a space, follow 'internal' semicolons with a space, place spaces inside of parens 3) place a space around each side of the C operators.

Comment: when possible, variable declarations should be kept close to where they are used.

Comment: the function: `isprime()` has one optimization `sqrt(n)` however it checks every number above 1.  That is very wasteful of CPU cycles,  Suggest 1) check for `n = 2`  and then the inner loop initialize `i` to 3, then use an increment of `i+=2`.   There are other optimizations possible, but just this modification will cut the number of loop iterations in half.

Comment: The function: `isprime()` does not always return the correct indication of 'is the passed in number prime?'  Suggest some logic re-design

Comment: when printing the results, pointed to by 'p', suggest using a loop, based on index 0...<j so all the 'prime' values are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` will return a new memory region each time in your loop, losing your previous data.

You need `realloc` instead

```
 int *p = NULL;  // initialize to NULL
```

and in the loop:

```
        p=realloc(p,j*sizeof(int));
```

so either `p` address is kept and memory increased, either previous data from  `p` is copied and a new `p` is issued. Either way it's transparent for you.

(First time, as `p` is `NULL`, it acts like `malloc`)

Note that it's rather inefficient to `realloc` at each iteration. It would be better to resize less often, and keep record of capacity and actual data length. For instance like this:

Init:

```
  int growth = 100;
  int capacity = 0;
  int *p = NULL;
```

and in the loop:

```
  if (j>=capacity)
  {
      capacity += growth;
      p = realloc(p,capacity*sizeof(int));
  }
```

Aside: as comments noted, for the answer to full work, don't omit last value when checking for primes or you'll detect perfect squares as primes.

Comment: you said it's inefficient to use realloc at each iteration then can you please suggest what should I do?